# php zip_entry_read issue

Tags: php, zip

I'm trying to create a PHP script that receives and extracts a zip file. The first thing I do  when i get the file is to try to extract the files inside to see if everything is okay and the folder structure of the zip is as it should. If all goes well, the script goes on and extracts the files. The problem is here. It seems that if I call `zip_entry_read()` once on a zip entry I get the content, but if I call it again on the same zip entry reference it returns nothing. The meta data is still there. `zip_entry_name()`, size and all that returns the correct data but not the content. **Why oh why ?**

Here's and example.

```
$target = zip_open("file.zip");
while (false !== ($entry = zip_read($target)) {
   // ... some code here
   $name = zip_entry_name($entry); // returns filename.txt
   $filesize = intval(zip_entry_filesize($entry)); // returns the filesize
   $data = zip_entry_read($entry, $filesize); // returns the content of the file

   $name = zip_entry_name($entry); // returns the same filename.txt
   $filesize = intval(zip_entry_filesize($entry)); // returns the same filesize
   $data = zip_entry_read($entry, $filesize); // ---> returns NOTHING <---
   // .. some more code here
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need close it and open again? Because in php help I see: _Returns the data read, or FALSE if the end of the file is reached._

Comment: Why are you trying to extract the data twice?

Comment: i don't explicitly read the data twice for the hell of it. the overall process requires some files to be read once in the validation step and then the installation process actually writes them to disk so it reads them again. and when it reaches this step, the content is null. If i save the file content at the first read in memory, then other extra checks should be done to see if the content can or cannot be read from zip, which is a stupid thing to do. I was trying to make it work with the defined methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a quick test, and the suggested solution (closing and opening the entry again) dosn't seem to work. The second execution still returns an empty string. Anyway since the zip_entry_read function return a simple string I would simply copy it in another variable, if it's not a problem.

[UPDATE]
Well, if copying the value is not an option, you can try the OO version of the [ZipArchive](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class (it's the object oriented version of the zip library). Something like the code below works and returns two times the desired zip entry. Maybe you can tailor it to your needs.

```
target = new ZipArchive();
$target->open("file.zip");

for($i = 0; $i < $target->numFiles; $i++)
{
    $stat = $target->statIndex($i);
    print_r($stat);
    $data = $target->getFromIndex($i);
    print_r($data);
    echo "<br />Control<br />"; 
    $data = $target->getFromIndex($i);
    print_r($data);
    echo "<br />Control<br />"; 

}
```

Comment: well, i thought of that. But the thing is the first pass is used to validate the zip file. If the zip is no good then nothing is done. If it is, the the zip entries are passed to some classes that know where each file goes based on some rules. I was hopping I can avoid holding all the extracted data in memory and make it work as it should with the read entry method.